# rasa entity extraction for dates other than duckling?

Tags: python, mysql, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I want to know if there is another entity extractor for dates in rasa other than duckling??

duckling requires other desktop to run like docker but docker keeps failing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [spacy](https://spacy.io/models). You can use their pretrained models in Rasa pipelines. Some of their pre-trained models also support dates and you can use these in Rasa. The easiest way to explore if this is available for your language is to use their [interactive demo found here](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent).

You can find more information on spaCy components in Rasa [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components#spacynlp). In particular you'll want to make sure your pipeline has a [spacy entity extractor](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components#spacyentityextractor).